# How to define multiple widget classes within a single plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add two widgets to a Wordpress plugin I'm developing. What is the correct way to call multiple classes?

I have a plugin folder containing my-plugin.php:

```
class WidgetA extends WP_Widget {
  function widget_a() {
    ...
  }
  function form($instance) {
    ...
  }
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    ...
  }
  function widget($args, $instance) {
    ...
  } 
}
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("WidgetA");'));

class WidgetB extends WP_Widget {
  function widget_b() {
    ...
  }
  function form($instance) {
    ...
  }
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    ...
  }
  function widget($args, $instance) {
    ...
  } 
}
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("WidgetB");'));
```

If I delete WidgetA then WidgetB functions correctly, and vice versa. But nothing is displayed if I include both classes.

What is the correct way to define two widgets/ classes in a plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare multiple widget classes into single plugin using below code :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'src_load_widgets' );

function src_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'WidgetA' );
    register_widget( 'WidgetB' );
}

class WidgetA extends WP_Widget {
    // ...
}

class WidgetB extends WP_Widget {
    // ...
}
```

Source : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47492/wordpress-multiple-widget-in-single-plugin